# Attribute Error - Scikit learn Huber Regressor

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Here is my code:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import HuberRegressor
model = HuberRegressor()
model.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_2620/1972884986.py in <module>
      1 from sklearn.linear_model import HuberRegressor
      2 model = HuberRegressor()
----> 3 model.fit(X_train,y_train)

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\_huber.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    294                              " l-BFGS-b solver terminated with %s"
    295                              % opt_res.message)
--> 296         self.n_iter_ = _check_optimize_result("lbfgs", opt_res, self.max_iter)
    297         self.scale_ = parameters[-1]
    298         if self.fit_intercept:

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\sklearn\utils\optimize.py in _check_optimize_result(solver, result, max_iter, extra_warning_msg)
    241                 "    https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/"
    242                 "preprocessing.html"
--> 243             ).format(solver, result.status, result.message.decode("latin1"))
    244             if extra_warning_msg is not None:
    245                 warning_msg += "\n" + extra_warning_msg

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at the latest version of scikit-learn [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/main/sklearn/utils/optimize.py), this may be fixed by updating your `scipy` and `scikit-learn`.